# Euclidean norm and spheres

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Let be $x\in S^n\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $0<\varepsilon<1$ and $u\in B^{n+1}_\varepsilon(x)$.

> 1) How can I prove that $\frac{u}{\lVert{u}\rVert}\in B^{n+1}_\epsilon(x)$?
>
> 2) If I want to say that for each $\lambda\in (a,b)$ I have $\lambda u\in B^{n+1}_\epsilon(x)$, how should I take $a$ and $b$ such that the interval $(a,b)$ is the largest possible?

Maybe I have succeded in showing the point 1) but I think there can be a smarter and shorter proof than mine.

Comment: Show us your proof then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim 1) is in fact false. Here is a counter-example:

Let $n=1$, $x=(1,0)$ and $\varepsilon=\frac12$. Then $u:=(\frac34, \frac{\sqrt3}4)\in  B^{n+1}_\varepsilon(x)$ since $u-x=(-\frac14,\frac{\sqrt3}4)$ and $\Vert u-x\Vert^2=\frac14$. But $\frac{u}{\Vert u\Vert}=\frac{(\frac34, \frac{\sqrt3}4)}{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}=(\frac{\sqrt3}{2},\frac12)$ and $\Vert\frac{u}{\Vert u\Vert}-x\Vert^2=2-\sqrt3>\frac14$.

Comment: I'd like to add that this still produces a counter-example even if we consider the $B^{n+1}_{\varepsilon}$ to be open balls. Since $\frac{u}{\|u\|}$ is a positive distance away from $B^{n+1}_{\varepsilon}(x)$, we can nudge $u$ slightly towards its interior and keep $\frac{u}{\|u\|}$ outside.

Comment: Jens Schwaiger Thank you, my intuition was fooled by a not very precise drawing. With $B_{\varepsilon}^{n+1}(x)$ I meant the open ball, but with the suggestion of @Sambo the answer of the first point is complete. Thank you both.

Comment: As for part 2) one could note that $\Vert\lambda  u-x\Vert^2<\varepsilon^2$ is an inequality which is quadratic with respect to $\lambda$.